# Spring Web Service Dynamically redirecting the request based on Soap Headers

Tags: spring-ws

I am working on Spring Web Service project, i have developed an Endpoint class which accepts request from SOAP UI, and provides the response.

Soap request has Header [some properties], Body [ request tag with some elements]

Now i have to change the Endpoint Invocation depending on the property passed in the header.
"Header has a property called operationVersion"

If i get operationVersion as 3 from soapheader, then i have to invoke my existing Endpoint, If i get operationVersion as 5 then i have to invoked another Endpoint which deals with Version 5 Response.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

How about to go with standard - `WS-Addressing`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#server-ws-addressing ?

Having that you will be able to to `route` your requests using something like this:

```
@Action("http://samples/RequestOrder")
public Order getOrder(OrderRequest orderRequest) {
    return orderService.getOrder(orderRequest.getId());
}

@Action("http://samples/CreateOrder")
public void order(Order order) {
    orderService.createOrder(order);
}
```

Otherwise you can achieve it only via a single method and routing within it:

```
public void handle(@RequestPayload DOMSource domSource, @SoapHeader("operationVersion") SoapHeaderElement header)
```